# What is a limit for number of threads?

Tags: process-management, multithreading

I was wondering how many processes can I create on my machine (x64 with 8Gb of RAM and running Ubuntu). So I made simple master process which was continiously creating child processes, and that child processes were just sleeping all the time. I ended with just 11-12k processes. Then I switched processes to threads and got exactly same result.
My pid_max is set to 32768, all per-user limits are disabled. Physical memory usage is just couple of bytes. Could you tell me what prevents the system to create new threads at that point?

p.s. here is my source code for multiprocessing test written in C

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    pid_t pid;
    int count = 0;
    while (1) {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1) {
            printf("total: %d\n", count);
            return 0;
        }
        if (pid == 0) {
            while (1) sleep(10);
        }
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `ulimit -u` report?

Comment: @dhag `ulimit -u` reports 31127

Comment: `errno` should be set when `pid == -1`, maybe that has clues?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344203/maximum-number-of-threads-per-process-in-linux for more information.

Comment: Why do you ask, and why does it matter? Do you really need that much processes or threads? What is the real world scenario justifying that? Very probably your computer will thrash before reaching that limit (e.g. having a thousand of runnable processes is not realistic in practice).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am curious about bottlenecks caused by thread usage (in context of nowadays hype with single-threaded application architecture, like node apps, go apps, nginx etc)

Comment: But these bottlenecks are hitting painfully long before you reach hard limits (on number of threads or processes). So you really should benchmark your actual code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I think you hit either a number of processes limit or a memory limit.**

When I try your program on my computer and reach the `pid == -1` state, `fork()` returns the error `EAGAIN`, with error message: `Resource temporarily unavailable`. **As a normal user**, I could create approx 15k processes.

There are several reasons this `EAGAIN` could happen, detailed in `man 2 fork`:

- not enough memory,
- hitting a limit like RLIMIT_NPROC,
- deadline scheduler specifics.

In my case, I think I just hit the `RLIMIT_NPROC` limit, aka what `ulimit -u` usually shows. The best is to display this limit within the program, so you have the real value, not your shell's limits.

```c
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

int main() {
    struct rlimit rlim;
    getrlimit(RLIMIT_NPROC, &rlim);
    printf("RLIMIT_NPROC soft: %d, hard: %d\n", rlim.rlim_cur, rlim.rlim_max);
```

Which yields:

```c
RLIMIT_NPROC soft: 15608, hard: 15608
total: 15242
```

Which looks reasonable as I have other processes running, including a web browser.

---

Now, **as root**, the limits don't really apply anymore and I could `fork()` much more: I created more than 30k processes, close to my 32k `pid_max`.

Now, if I take my **normal user** shell's PID (`echo $$`), and **as root** in another shell, I do: `prlimit --pid $SHELLPID --nproc=30000`, and *then* launch your program in this shell, I can create almost 30k processes:

```c
RLIMIT_NPROC soft: 30000, hard: 30000
total: 29678
```

---

Finally: you should also consider memory usage, because on my system, I used ***a lot*** of RAM and swap to create all those processes, and maybe it was the limit you hit. Check with `free`.

Comment: Control group tasks maxima have an effect too, in addition to POSIX resource limits; quite famously on systemd operating systems like Ubuntu 15 and 16.